# ora-01722 odd behavior

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm facing some odd behavior on a query on an Oracle db.
I'm only contacting the db, so I don't have any influence on its structure.

My problem lies in the column "entrydate", its defined as a column `NUMBER(14,0)` and contains a date formatted as `yyyyMMddhhmmss` (as a rule by our supplier)

What I'm encountering is the following:

```
Select sum(col1 + col2 + col3) as summedcount
from traces
where ProductID = 123456 and entrydate > 20170911060000;
```

The above query results in a correct answer, whereas

```
Select sum(col1 + col2 + col3) as summedcount
from traces
where ProductID = 123456 and entrydate > 20170111060000;
```

results in an `ORA-01722` error...
Only thing I change is checking January instead of September...

I understand the `ORA-1722` occurs when you're not providing clean INT-values, but in this case I never do...

Could someone provide me with an insight in what I'm missing here?

Edit:
As an extra I ran `SELECT * FROM traces WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(entrydate, '[^0-9]+')`to make sure I was only having numerical values in that column, and that seems to be the case!

Comment: `to make sure I was only having numerical values in that column, and that seems to be the case!` - do you mean that entry date contains only numerical values or do you mean that this is the case because it contains non-numerical values ?

Comment: Run "select col1,col2,col3,,," and see what the values are, as one of them is not a number.

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity: entrydate does only contain numericals

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct.  I ran your regex at 'regexr.com' and it didn't work as expected.  With your syntax I would return all values that are alphabetical, whereas '[0-9]+' would return just INT values.

Comment: You are right, however I was using [^0-9]+ (so inverting it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` are really `numbers`, then you would not get a format error there.

That leaves `ProductId`.  Is it stored as a string?  If so, you should be using:

```
where ProductID = '123456' and . . .
```

Optimizers can be funny things.  The engine might be filtering on date first.  So, if all the product ids are correct for January then one might be wrong for September.

Oh, on second thought, the problem could also be the date -- assuming the product id is okay.  If it is not stored as a number, then you might want:

```
where ProductID = 123456 and entrydate > '20170111060000'
```

or:

```
where ProductID = 123456 and entrydate > TIMESTAMP '2017-01-11T06:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help: I just ran the regex agains ProductID and turns out that the first -ever- added lines in the DB are containing chars! That's unfortunate...

FIXED! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your col1, col2 and col3 contain strictly numbers as well, this error might very well be raised by `SUM`

Comment: thanks for the tip! However all of those turn out to be numeric as well. They are also defined as `NUMBER(9.0)`